# Problem with HTML padding overflowing an empty block when using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap in my project and encountered a problem when the browser shows that "section categories" is full. But this block contains an empty "div container". I think that the reason is a conflict between the paddings I specified for categories and the native bootstrap paddings for categories. But I can’t understand the reason for this conflict and how to correctly set left and right padding for categories. Can anyone explain?

```
        <section class="categories ">
            <div class="container">

            </div>
        </section>
```

```
.categories{
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 3.5em 8em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

I need padding for categories but I didn't expect that padding could overflow an empty block without a directly specified height and width